# Capacitance and battery and no resistor and time

Tags: voltage, capacitor

I already know the 't=RC' . But what happens if I start charging a capacitor via a same voltage battery? When will it be fully charged?

Comment: The battery will have an internal resistance, so that's the missing part of the equation. Also the time constant above isn't for it to be fully charged.

Comment: Hmmmm.... I heard something about internal resistance but I didn't believe it , thanks anyway!

Comment: What do you mean "I didn't believe it"? That's not something you can't believe in...

Comment: I mean , batteries , with resistance that is wasting energy?

Comment: Also the wires have a resistance, of course. There is no such thing as a [perfect conductor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_conductor) (R=0). You can read up on internal resistance [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_resistance).

Comment: @user3029101 - "I mean , batteries , with resistance that is wasting energy?" Dude. Do this, will you? Take a AAA battery and short the outputs with a short piece of, let's say, 22 ga wire. How much current do  you get? Why don't you get more? Resistivity of 22 ga is ~35 ohms per 1000 ft, so 3 inches will be ~ .001 ohms. The current "ought" to be 1.5 volts / .001 ohms, or ~1500 amps. Why doesn't the wire explode? And why does the battery get warm?

Comment: Stuff designed to be shorted? Good.

Comment: @CamilSteps superconductors do exist, for constrained conditions.

Comment: The battery manufacturers don't intentionally install resistors inside batteries.  The internal reistance of a battery is an unavoidable by-product of the battery construction, and the nature of the chemical reactions in the battery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know that T = RC, then you know that when T gets to RC the capacitor will only be charged up to about 63% of the battery voltage.

Then, after another RC passes the capacitor will have charged up to about 63% of the difference between the battery voltage and the voltage across the capacitor at the end of the last RC.

Then, after another RC passes the capacitor will have charged up to about 63% of the difference between the battery voltage and the voltage across the capacitor at the end of the last RC.

And so on, forever, so you can see that since the charge is exponential the capacitor never really charges up to the battery voltage completely.

This sketch pretty much says it all for the first RC, and if there's no intended resistance in there, then R is equal to the sum of the battery's internal resistance, the wiring resistance, and the capacitor's equivalent series resistance:

[image]